# Sending a null callback

Tags: c++, callback

I have a case in my code where I have to send an empty callback, in c++. Here is what I have:

```
class SomeClass {
...
typedef boost::function<void()> Callback;
void someFunction(int a, Callback callback = NULL);
...
}


//in another function of SomeClass, I create a boost::bind refering this someFunction:

_view->setCallback(boost::bind(&SomeClass::someFunction, this, _1, 0));
```

It is giving me an error as it does not know how to interpretate this 0 for the Callback parameter. How can I tell it to send a null callback or something like it?

Thanks

Comment: Why use NULL rather than an empty function? NULL-checks usually just creates more convoluted logic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an object reference as the default value, instead of `NULL`

```
class SomeClass {
...
typedef boost::function<void()> Callback;
static Callback g_NullCallback;
void someFunction(int a, Callback callback = g_NullCallback);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it yourself

```
void NullFunc() {};
```

and then

```
void someFunction(int a, Callback callback = NullFunc);
```